# Is it possible to define different return types on Go unit tests

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement unit test for Go client. Can I leave the `want` in the Unit Test to infer the type?

```
var halfTests = []struct {
    in  int
    want type1 | type2
}{
    {1, type1},
    {3, type2},
}
```

I checked this: [Options for different return types based on argument](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/zlb0v0/options_for_different_return_types_based_on/)

Comment: Why not use an interface?

Comment: What unit are you testing that will produce different types of outputs?

Comment: It is not possible for a function to have two different return types like this, so it is not possible to need to test such a function. Can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's hard to test, that could indicate a design problem with the test or the code. Ask yourself why this unit of code can produce two different types of output in the same test. Perhaps your "unit test" is testing too much at once. Perhaps the unit's interface could be reworked.

If you decide that yes, it really should be like that, define an interface of common methods of type1 and type2 that you intend the caller to use.

If there is no common interface, again question the design of the test and the unit being tested; why is a unit returning two unrelated types?

If you still feel this is necessary, use `interface {}`. The caller must use a type switch to check the type. See [Interfaces In Golang](https://golangdocs.com/interfaces-in-golang).